# React optional field validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui

I have a register form with next fields:

1. Name
2. Email
3. Password
4. Confirm password
5. Optional field
6. Select role( student, professor, secretary)

What I want is:

If I want to create a user with **student** role, optional field should **not be considered**, but if I want to create a **professor/secretary** user, then I will have to type a certain password in optional field (https://prnt.sc/159y5x9)

This is my Register function:

```
function Register() {
const [user, setUser] = useState(initialState)
const pswdProfesor = "profpassword"  //password needed for professor role
const pswdSecretar = "secretpasswor" // password needed for secretary role

const {name, email, password,cf_password, role, err, success} = user

const handleChangeInput = e => {
    const {name, value} = e.target
    setUser({...user, [name]:value, err: '', success: ''})
}

const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(isEmpty(name) || isEmpty(password) || isEmpty(role))
            return setUser({...user, err: "Completati campurile", success: ''})

    if(!isEmail(email))
        return setUser({...user, err: "Email invalid", success: ''})

    if(isLength(password))
        return setUser({...user, err: "Parola trebuie sa fie minim 6 caractere", success: ''})
    
    if(!isMatch(password, cf_password))
        return setUser({...user, err: "Parola nu coincide", success: ''})

    // validation for Optional field here //

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/user/register', {
            name, email, password, role
        })

        setUser({...user, err: '', success: res.data.msg})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("hello")

        err.response.data.msg && 
        setUser({...user, err: err.response.data.msg, success: ''})
    }
}
```

PS: im using React and Material UI TextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
    // validation for Optional field here //

   if(role === "professor" || role === "secretary "){
    if (isEmpty(optional)) {
      return setUser({ ...user, err: "Optional field is required", success: "" });
    }
  }
```

or

```
// validation for Optional field here //

   if(!isEmpty(role) && role !== "student"){
      if (isEmpty(optional)) {
        return setUser({ ...user, err: "Optional field is required", success: "" });
      }
    }
```

or

```
// validation for Optional field here //

   if(!isEmpty(role) && role !== "student" && isEmpty(optional)){
        return setUser({ ...user, err: "Optional field is required", success: "" });
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i took the first one and modified it a little and now it works